# What is the MSB of each seven segment in ARMv7 DE1-SoC in cpulator?

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded, seven-segment-display

In the cpulator website, when i want to show a number on the seven segment displays, it tells me to change an specific memory location which i assume is connected to the displays. i can understand the meaning of the 7 last least significant bits of each seven segment(a,b,c,d,e,f,g). but for the MSB it looks like it doesnt matter what i enter there;0 or 1 will show the same value.

For example when i enter [ff(1111 1111)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNqxX.png) or [7f(0111 1111)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qX6X.png) the display will show me the number `8`.

Can someone please explain to me what is the purpose of the MSB of the 8-bit input of the seven segments?

Comment: What makes you think that bit has any purpose?  A byte has eight bits, the display has seven segments, one bit gets left over.  (A likely use for an 8th bit in conjunction with a 7-seg display would be for the decimal point - but not all displays have that feature.)

Comment: Hmmm... i thought it may have an special function which will be interpretted by the decoder circuit.

Comment: Your screenshots show all segments lit for both bit-patterns, displaying the number `8` (eight), not `0` (zero), as expected.  I fixed that for you while editing tags.

Comment: The 8th bit could be used for the decimal point if your seven-segment display has it.  Have you tried setting it?

Comment: Yes i did set it but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers generally organize information into bytes, which are 8 bits.  I bet the most significant bit is just there because you have a byte and it serves no particular purpose.  In actual microcontrollers there are unimplemented bits in special function registers all the time, and they read as a fixed value (usually 0).